# Saving the results of a query to use in an IN comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Is it possible to save the results of a query into a variable and be able to use it in an IN statement

Example:

```
...

declare @ListOfValues ?DATA TYPE? = select Values from tblValueList

while exists (select top 1 RecordID From @tblResults)
begin
    If @variable in (@ListOfValues)
    begin
        ...
```

Since it is bad practice to query inside of a loop (assumption from front end development), what is the best practice to do something like this in back end development?

Comment: Can you be more specific if you need solution for Mysql or TSql(SQLServer) ? SQLServer lets you have table variable, so you can insert your values into it, and you can join it in the next query...

Comment: There isn't a generic enough solution that could be applied to all types of databases?  I am working in t-sql at the moment, but I also worked in mysql in the past.  I'm asking this question for my own education, not for any specific task at hand :/

Comment: RDMS are quite different. As I said, SQLServer has table variable, Oracle has very similar concept `table of object`; with mysql I believe the only way to avoid iterations is to use temporary tables

Comment: @a1ex07 - so with a table variable you could do `IN (#tableVar)` or `IN (@tableVar)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to your question is "No".  Also, I don't fully understand your pseudo-SQL.  Where does @variable come from?

In any case, there are three answers to your question:

(1) The simplest is to store the list of values in a temporary table.  Then you can delete each one in the while loop.

(2) You can use cursors to go through the elements.

(3) You could concatenate the values into a string, and do complicated string manipulation in the while loop.

Comment: So there is no way to make an "array" of a results from a SELECT statement to use in an IN comparison?

Comment: Not in standard SQL.  You get pretty close by putting the values in a temporary table (or using a with statement), and using something like "in (select * from temptable)".